# "Synchronize message" with a Large folder with Outlook REST API

Tags: rest, office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I am using the beta endpoint Office365 Outlook REST API to synchronize a large Office365 Outlook folder, see doc [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#Synchronizemessagespreview).

The response is paginated... and after many calls to the first synchronization of this big folder, I received this error:

```
{"error":{"code":"LocalTime","message":"This operation exceeds the throttling budget for policy part 'LocalTime', policy value '0',  Budget type: 'Ews'.  Suggested backoff time 299499 ms."}}
```

Looks like I have requested too much the API. What is the best way to handle it? Should I implement some kind of retry policy?

Comment: For information, the errors is raised after polling 39 000 items with page of 500 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is our current throttling mechanism, which is a temporary measure while our "real" throttling implementation is being deployed. To handle this, you'll need to do a retry after about 5 minutes.